# Bootstrap - container com duas colunas e duas linhas com mesmo tamanho

Tags: bootstrap

Boas,
Estou a tentar fazer um container com 4 células iguais, isto é, 2 colunas e 2 linhas.
Já experimentei usar col e row mas nada dá certo.

Tenho isto apenas, neste momento.

```html
<div id="container">
        <video autoplay="true" id="video"></video>
</div>
```

Comment: Usa col e row e tenta fazer um estilo com video { width: 100% }

Answer (score 1):

Houve uma alteração na forma de se construir *grids* do  **bootstrap 3** para o **bootstrap 4**

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          coluna (0,1)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          coluna (0,2)
        </div>   
      <div class="w-100"></div>  
      <div class="col">
          coluna (1,1)
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          coluna (1,2)
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Confira a documentação: `https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/`

Answer (score 1):

Não sei qual **Bootstrap** está utilizando, se for o anterior ao **4**, da para fazer assim. Clique em executar e página toda, para visualizar como em tela desktop.

```css
video {
    margin-top: 20px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <video autoplay="true" id="video1">
              <source src="">
             </video>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <video autoplay="true" id="video2"></video>
             <source src="">
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <video autoplay="true" id="video3"></video>
             <source src="">
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
             <video autoplay="true" id="video4"></video>
             <source src="">
         </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```